# Flutter how to achieve scaling animation effect in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I am trying to achieve an animation effect where a user can swipe the widget and the emoji will switch position the right will move to the center and get bigger while the old center moves to left and becomes smaller

[image: animation object]